# Deleting whitespaces from certain points of a string

Tags: c++, string

So my problem is that I have to delete whitespaces from a string, but only in certain places of the string. I have a program that reads a .txt file line by line and the lines in the file can be the following kind:

```
|sometext:anothertext|

|some text   :  anothertext|

|some text:another text |

| sometext    :    anothertext  |
```

'|' is marking the start and the end of the line.

Now I only need to delete the whitespaces at front and back of the line, and next to the ':'.

Edit: seems that regex is the easiest way to do this

Comment: Well, for contextual string replacement, I'd use a regex, sth like [`^\s+|\s+$|\s*(:)\s*` -> `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/J1wguG/1).

Comment: You've described us what you're trying to do, and you've shown us a program. Does the program not do what  you describe? If not, then what does it do? What is the problem?

Comment: When I run it, it gives me an error on the first line read from the file:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 20) >= this->size() (which is 20)

Comment: your while loops have fixed conditions, they will either be infinite loops or null loops.

Comment: Pretty much every line in the shown code is completely wrong. It would take several paragraphs to point out each and every bug. I count at least six of them. You need to get rid of this entirely, spend a day, or two, reading your C++ book, and start again, from scratch.

Comment: After looking into it, seems that using regex is the easiest way.

Comment: A regex would be one option; but I wouldn't say it's the easiest one. Using `<iterator>` and `<algorithm>`, this should be about five lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I have a utility class that has a bunch of static methods for working with strings; I'll just show the relevant function for doing trimming of whitespaces as well as a method to split a string or to tokenize a string using a delimiting substring or character.

**Utility.h**

```
#ifndef UTILITY_H
#define UTILITY_H

class Utility {
public:
    static std::string  trim( const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim = " \t\n\r" );
    static std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty = true ); 

private:
    Utility(); // Private - Not A Class Object
    Utility( const Utility& c ); // Not Implemented
    Utility& operator=( const Utility& c ); // Not Implemented

}; // Utility

#endif // UTILITY_H
```

**Utility.cpp**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utility.h"    

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// trim()
// Removes Elements To Trim From Left And Right Side Of The str
std::string Utility::trim(const std::string& str, const std::string elementsToTrim) {
    std::basic_string<char>::size_type firstIndex = str.find_first_not_of(elementsToTrim);
    if (firstIndex == std::string::npos) {
        return std::string(); // Nothing Left
    }

    std::basic_string<char>::size_type lastIndex = str.find_last_not_of(elementsToTrim);
    return str.substr(firstIndex, lastIndex - firstIndex + 1);
} // trim    

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// splitString()
std::vector<std::string> Utility::splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty ) {
    std::vector<std::string> vResult;
    if ( strDelimiter.empty() ) {
        vResult.push_back( strStringToSplit );
        return vResult;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = strStringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while ( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = search( itSubStrStart, strStringToSplit.end(), strDelimiter.begin(), strDelimiter.end() );
        std::string strTemp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );
        if ( keepEmpty || !strTemp.empty() ) {
            vResult.push_back( strTemp );
        }

        if ( itSubStrEnd == strStringToSplit.end() ) {
            break;
        }

        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + strDelimiter.size();
    }

    return vResult;    
} // splitString
```

These methods should help you and to use them just include the header and where needed use the scope resolution operator since these methods are static and you can not instantiate or define a "utility object".

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Utility.h"

int main() {
    std::string myString( "TwoWords" );
    std::string delimiter( "Two" );
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    words = Utility::splitString( myString, delimiter );
    // Or
    words = Utility::splitString( myString, std::string( " " ) );
    // Or
    words = Utility:splitString( myString, " " );

    std::string sentence( " Hello World! " );

    sentence = Utility::trim( sentence ); // 2nd Parameter Default To Whitespace

    return 0;
}
```

Now you could modify these methods to suite your needs, but this is the general idea that I use for a reusable string manipulating library.